# Quasar: Drawer changes to automatically Mini-mode

Tags: vue.js, responsive, quasar-framework, drawer

I am using Quasar, and I would like the `drawer` changes into `mini` mode automatically whenever the browser gets smaller by users. For now, it's always opened even I narrows the browser.

It's what I tried below:

```js
    <q-drawer
      v-model="drawer"
      show-if-above
      :mini="!drawer || miniState"
      @click.capture="drawerClick"
      :width="220"
      :breakpoint="500"
      bordered
      :content-style="{ backgroundColor: '#f5f7f9' }"
    >
      <q-scroll-area class="fit">
        <q-list padding>
          <q-btn
            v-if="!miniState"
            flat
            left
            @click="miniState = !miniState"
            class="logo-btn"
          >
            <img
              src="~assets/os_logo.png"
              width="144px"
              height="24px"
              contain
            />
          </q-btn>
          <q-btn v-else flat left @click="miniState = !miniState">
            <img src="~assets/os_logo_no_text.png" width="24px" contain />
          </q-btn>

          <!-- MENU -->
          <q-expansion-item
            default-opened
            v-for="(menu, index) in menus"
            :style="index === 0 && 'margin-top: 27px'"
            :icon="menu.icon"
            :label="menu.title"
            :key="menu.id"
            :expand-icon="menu.subMenus.length === 0 ? 'none' : ''"
            header-class="header-bg text-black"
            expand-icon-class="text-gray"
          >
            <q-expansion-item
              v-for="(sub, index) in menu.subMenus"
              :key="index"
              :label="sub.title"
              expand-icon="none"
              class="sub-content"
              :to="{ name: sub.link }"
            />
          </q-expansion-item>
        </q-list>
      </q-scroll-area>
    </q-drawer>
```

And the script code below :

```js
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
export default Vue.extend({
  // name: 'ComponentName'
  data() {
    return {
      drawer: false,
      miniState: false,
  },
  computed: { // <-- I tried this one..
    miniState() {
      if (window.innerWidth < 600) {
        return (this.miniState = true);
      }
    }
  },
  });
</script>
```

I have also checked this answers here : [How to default navigation drawer to closed on mobile and open on desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65552492/how-to-default-navigation-drawer-to-closed-on-mobile-and-open-on-desktop)

But this is not really what I am aiming for since the mode of `drawer` gets stuck and not changes responsively. Any suggestions?

Comment: In your code you do not have any logic to watch the browser resize.

Comment: @Chin.Udara Umm, you mean `watch()`?

Comment: Not specifically a `watch`, but you can achieve the same with a `computed` property too. My point is, that logic is not there in the code you have put above.

Comment: @Chin.Udara I actually have tried that one too, but it did not work out. It didn't detect the screen size in real-time, but kept it once..

Comment: Can you update your code with whatever you have tried please?

Comment: @Chin.Udara I have already erased them, but I will try and update in a jiffy!

Comment: @Chin.Udara I eidted, but this ain't what I had tired before.. I spent so many times here but no luck..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you have made several mistakes;

1. You are repeating your data property `miniState` as a computed property. The `miniState` property inside the data function will override the computed property; thus it will always be `false`
2. You are not returning a value from your computed property; instead you are only assigning.
3. Still; window properties such as `innerWidth` is not reactive and watchable in Vue. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thus, watching `window.innerWidth` will not trigger every time the window is resized.

Since you are using Quasar, you can make use of the the `screen` plugin which comes with Quasar. You dont have to install anything, the `screen` plugin is installed by default. [Here is the link to the docs.](https://quasar.dev/options/screen-plugin#introduction)

I have put below a very minimal example of the code with the functionality you required. This is not the code you have put in your post above. I extracted the drawer and the content from the Quasar documentation [here](https://quasar.dev/layout/drawer#mouseover-mouseout-trigger)

Now the drawer will automatically go into `mini` mode when the screen size is below `500 px`; this is of course configurable.

Also; on a side note, if you are only starting with Vue and Quasar, Vue is now upgraded to `Vue3` which comes with the [composition api](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html). Quasar is also being [upgraded to version 2](https://next.quasar.dev/introduction-to-quasar) which supports `Vue3`.

Follow the comments below and you will understand the code!

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#q-app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      drawer: true,
      // using a property to track when to show the mini drawer: this way is easy to maintain.
      switchToMini: 500
    }
  },
  computed: {
    // use ministate as a computed property
    miniState: function() {
      // use the screen plugin of Quasar -> this is very handy
      return this.$q.screen.width < this.switchToMini
      // you can do better and compare agains Quasars default breakpoints; following code checks whether the current screen size is 'sm'. You can comapare against 'xs', 'sm', 'md', 'lg' and 'xl'
      // return this.$q.screen.name === "sm"
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!-- quasar and vue includes -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@quasar/extras/material-icons/material-icons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar/dist/quasar.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar/dist/quasar.umd.min.js"></script>
<!-- end of includes -->

<!-- app -->
<div id="q-app">
  <template>
      <div class="q-pa-md">
        <q-layout view="hHh Lpr lff" container style="height: 300px" class="shadow-2 rounded-borders">
          <q-header elevated class="bg-black">
            <q-toolbar>
              <q-toolbar-title>Header</q-toolbar-title>
            </q-toolbar>
          </q-header>

          <q-drawer
            v-model="drawer"
            show-if-above

            :mini="miniState"
            :breakpoint="200"
            :width="200"
            bordered
            class="bg-grey-3"
          >
            <q-scroll-area class="fit">
              <q-list padding>
                <q-item clickable v-ripple>
                  <q-item-section avatar>
                    <q-icon name="send" />
                  </q-item-section>
                  <q-item-section>
                    Send
                  </q-item-section>
                </q-item>
              </q-list>
            </q-scroll-area>
          </q-drawer>

          <q-page-container>
            <q-page padding>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit nihil praesentium molestias a adipisci, dolore vitae odit, quidem consequatur optio voluptates asperiores pariatur eos numquam rerum delectus commodi perferendis voluptate?
              </p>
            </q-page>
          </q-page-container>
        </q-layout>
      </div>
    </template>
</div>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help and detailed explanation! I am still a newbie, so don't have a strong fundamental knowledge on either `vue` or `quasar`, but thanks for your kind explanation, now I know the notion of `compouted`.  And yes, I knew the existence of `screen` plugin inside `Quasar`, but did not work, so i just left out it. Now i know why it didn't work from the very first place. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Golden answer! Did not know about the screen plugin.